# Get a range of lines from a file given the start and end line numbers

Tags: unix, shell

I need to extract a set number of lines from a file given the start line number and end line number.

How could I quickly do this under unix (it's actually Solaris so gnu flavour isn't available).

Thx

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429556/shell-bash-command-to-get-nth-line-of-stdout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I extract a predetermined range of lines from a text file on Unix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83329/how-can-i-extract-a-predetermined-range-of-lines-from-a-text-file-on-unix)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

To print lines 6-10:

```
sed -n '6,10p' file
```

If the file is huge, and the end line number is small compared to the number of lines, you can make it more efficient by:

```
sed -n '10q;6,10p' file
```

From testing a file with a fairly large number of lines:

```
$ wc -l test.txt 
368048 test.txt
$ du -k test.txt 
24640    test.txt
$ time sed -n '10q;6,10p' test.txt >/dev/null
real   0m0.005s
user   0m0.001s
sys    0m0.003s
$ time sed -n '6,10p' test.txt >/dev/null
real   0m0.123s
user   0m0.092s
sys    0m0.030s
```

Comment: AAARRGGH!! :) that's better than mine

Comment: I thought of that but couldn't get it to stop printing the other lines.. the -n option.. :)

Comment: @Alok what does the 10q stand for?  Would I use 100000q if I want to get 100,000 lines?

Comment: @arc, yes, that's correct.  Specifically, `10q` means that for line 10, run command `q`, which is "quit".  So, `sed` will quit at line 10.

Comment: you can also use regular expressions to define start and end of matching.

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
head -n "$last" file | tail -n +"$first"
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Haskell program called [splitter](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/splitter) that does exactly this: have a [read through my release blog post](http://robertmassaioli.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/a-line-based-file-splitter-for-the-command-line/).

You can use the program as follows:

```
$ cat somefile | splitter 4,6-10,50-
```

That will get lines four, six to ten and lines fifty onwards. And that is all that there is to it. You will need Haskell to install it. Just:

```
$ cabal install splitter
```

And you are done. I hope that you find this program useful.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with nawk as well

```
#!/bin/sh
start=10
end=20
nawk -vs="$start" -ve="$end" 'NR>e{exit}NR>=s' file
```