# seek to a line in a file and display it on linux

Tags: linux

how to seek to a line and display it in a file on linux without opening the file?  are there any commands that can be useful? The file is rather large and can't be opened in memory.

Comment: add more details, any programming language? what shell? what do you mean by 'without opening the file'? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429556/shell-bash-command-to-get-nth-line-of-stdout

Comment: There is no reason an entire file has to memory resident to search through it.  Normally just little chunks are read at a time until the search is satisfied or eof is reached.  Opening the file is pretty much non-negotiable.

Comment: If you expect to get at the contents without opening a file, I certainly hope you’re chummy with the superblock.

Comment: "lines" are defined by the locations of "line separator" characters (in UN*X: CR, aka `\n`), which can occur anywhere in the file at any frequency. Unless your specific file has a far more rigid structure than that (like, all lines having the same number of characters), to make the position of the N-th line predictable somehow, there's no way to determine in advance where in the file "line `N`" starts without reading the entire file to that point and counting line separators as you go. You don't need to keep the entire file in memory while doing so - discard the already-processed parts.

Answer (score 2):

http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt shows an example of showing a single line from a file. It must open the file to read it but should stream through the contents without loading the entire thing into memory.

> `sed '52q;d'                  # method 3, efficient on large files`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enough room on your file system to split the file up?  [If so, try this](http://www.johnrockefeller.net/linuxunix-using-split-and-cat-to-split-large-files-for-transfer/):

```
$ split -b 1024m <filename>
```

> This will split your file into as many parts as needed, in 1024MB
>   chunks, typically with the name starting as xaa, xab, xac, and so on.

```
cat xa* | grep yourpattern
```

And when you're done:

```
rm xa*
```

Comment: I guess grep -rn 'searchpattern' will also do the pretty much same thing