# Read words in a specific line in a text file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, csv, file-processing

In my Bash shell script, I would like to read a specific line from a file; that is delimited by `:` and assign each section to a variable for processing later.

For example I want to read the words found on line 2. The text file:

```
abc:01APR91:1:50
Jim:02DEC99:2:3
banana:today:three:0
```

Once I have "read" line 2, I should be able to echo the values as something like this:

```
echo "$name";
echo "$date";
echo "$number";
echo "$age";
```

The output would be:

```
Jim
02DEC99
2
3
```

Comment: [bash split string into array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10586153)

Answer (score 6):

For echoing a single line of a file, I quite like `sed`:

```
$ IFS=: read name date number age < <(sed -n 2p data)
$ echo $name
Jim
$ echo $date
02DEC99
$ echo $number
2
$ echo $age
3
$
```

This uses [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) to get the output of `sed` to the `read` command.  The `sed` command uses the `-n` option so it does not print each line (as it does by default); the `2p` means 'when it is line 2, print the line'; `data` is simply the name of the file.

Comment: Incidentally, one advantage of this technique is that if the name is `Jim Kennedy` instead of just `Jim`, this gets the correct value into `$name`.  The other answers will have problems with `Kennedy` being the date, `02DEC99` being the number, and `2 3` being the age.

Comment: Intrigued by your excellent -n 2p sed modifier but unable to find it in the documentation. Found this explaination: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1429628/1207958

Comment: @svante: I'm practicing DRY — Don't Repeat Yourself.  :D   I'll add some comments to explain the `sed` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
read name date number age <<< $(awk -F: 'NR==2{printf("%s %s %s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4)}' inFile)

echo "$name"
echo "$date"
echo "$number"
echo "$age"
```